# Make assoc-id for collection conditionally in clojure

Tags: clojure

I made assoc-in like this

```
(defn process-pubaccess-nb [conn books]
  (map #(assoc-in % [:book/publication :publication/access] (get-rules-ids % conn) ) books)
  )
```

I want to add condition don't made **assoc-in** if **get-rules-ids** returns nil. I tried to add when-let, but I had errors.

For example if I get

```
(def lib [{:book/name "one" :book/pid "1" :book/publication {:publication/pid "11"} }
          {:book/name "two" :book/pid "2":book/publication {:publication/pid "22"} }
          {:book/name "three" :book/pid "3" }])
```

I want to have

```
    ({:book/name "one", :book/pid "1", :book/publication {:publication/pid "11", :publication/access "test"}} 
{:book/name "two", :book/pid "2", :book/publication {:publication/pid "22", :publication/access "test"}} 
{:book/name "three", :book/pid "3"})
```

Now I have without condition

```
({:book/name "one", :book/pid "1", :book/publication {:publication/pid "11", :publication/access "test"}} 
{:book/name "two", :book/pid "2", :book/publication {:publication/pid "22", :publication/access "test"}} 
{:book/name "three", :book/pid "3", :book/publication {:publication/access nil}})
```

Comment: Pass your collection through `filter` before going through the map/assoc-in and discard `books` that don't have `publication` information. Also what is `get-rules` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxx

Amar's solution works but it isn't clear the cost of calling `get-rules-ids` versus pre-filtering the collection.

Here is the filtered option for posterity:

```
    (defn process-pubaccess-nb 
      [conn books]
        (map #(assoc-in % [:book/publication :publication/access] (get-rules-ids % conn)) 
            (filter :book/publication books)))
```

Also, if the collection may be considerable in size, transducers could be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with if-let.

```clj
(defn process-pubaccess-nb
  [conn books]
  (map #(if-let [access (get-rules-ids % conn)]
          (assoc-in % [:book/publication :publication/access] access)
          %)
       books))
```